# Make an cocoa window TOPMOST between all running applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I've created a Cocoa application made of a little window that needs to be the topmost window between ALL running application. E.g.: if iTunes is also running my window needs to stay on top.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the window level (`NSStatusWindowLevel` or `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` should do the trick to keep on top of all running apps):

**ADC:**

- [Window Layers and Levels](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/WindowLevel.html)
- [Window Level Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**CocoaDev:**

- [WindowLevels](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSWindowLevel)